# Playing a video before the main screen of the app

Tags: android

in my app i want to add a video before the main screen shows up. That means when clicked on the icon of the app, it should show a video (for eg. as seen in games before they start) . can anyone tell me how it is done.

Answer (score 2):

Commonly, there is a "splash screen" activity that displays a graphic/video and launches your "main screen" activity after few seconds (or after the video is over). This "splash screen" should be manifested as the one to be started by the application launcher in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Further, store a boolean in Preferences that says whether this is the first run of the app. If so, play the video in the launcher activity. Otherwise, you can start your main activity and finish the launcher one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do Google for the same. but still FYI, there is already [**VideoView**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) provided by android.

XML:

```
 <VideoView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/videoView1">
    </VideoView>
```